# "Repeated" group in Forms for password validation

Tags: forms, symfony

I am using the 'repeated' field to validate a password in the form. 
According to the documentation, the 'repeated' field group is supposed 
to, render two identical fields (which it is doing) and submit only if 
the values from both the fields match or it should throw a validation error. The 
second part somehow does not seem to work. I tried using the example 
code as is but, the form submits with no issue or error even if the 
passwords do not match. Did anyone else come across the same issue or 
is there something I am doing wrong?

I did not add a validation file nor do I use annotations. From what I understand from the documentation, the repeated filed checks the values from first_name and second_name fields automatically and submits the form only when both the values are equal which it is not doing. This is the code I am using,

```
->add('password', 'repeated',
            array(
                'type' => 'password',
            )
        )
```

This renders two fields 'First' and 'Second' and passes an array with the 'First' and 'Second' values on submit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was a stupid mistake on my part. I was not validating the form in the controller. Once, I do that it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

the correct syntax would be

```
    ->add('tmpPassword', 'repeated', array('type' => 'password'));
```

if you use the the same key for the field as for the type it can not assign the value correct.

Comment: No change, still throws out the same array with both the values entered in the password fields.